# Asymptotic Big Omega Proof

Tags: asymptotics, constants

Let $f(n) = 2n^4 − 4n^3 + 16n^2 − 64^n + 3$.

(a) Using the constant $c = 1.9$, prove that $f(n) \in \Omega(n^4)$.

Just by looking at it it is clear to me that this is true as for $f(n) \in \Omega(n^4)$ to be true, $f(n) \ge 1.9n^4$ which is true. I just don't know how to prove it on paper. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

(b) Let $\epsilon$ be any positive real number. Prove that $f(n) \in \Omega(n^4)$ using the constant $c = 2 − \epsilon$ in the definition of big-Omega. Hint: Your $n_0$ is allowed to depend on $\epsilon$.

Answer (score 1):

(a) I would use the limit test. By showing $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{1.9n^{4}} \to \infty$, you get $f(n) \in \Omega(n^{1.4})$. Alternatively, you can prove this by induction.

(b) Again, the limit test is your friend.

Comment: Hi, is it possible if you could provide some hint on how to do this using induction?

Comment: You simply show that $f(n) \leq 1.9n^{4}$, for all $n \geq x$, for some $x \in \mathbb{N}$. How would you show that $2^{n} \leq n!$ for $n \geq 4$ by induction? There is also a good link here which shows a Big-O proof by induction. The concept is the same for Big-Omega. http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/280815-introduction-to-proofs-induction-and-big-o/

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to solve this by using a way that the school has taught us. do you know how n0 is obtained. many of the examples i'm looking at the n0 seem to just be pulled out

Comment: Note if the term is $64n$ rather than $64^{n}$, then you just solve for $n_{0}$ as $\epsilon n^{4} - 4n^{3} + 16n^{2} - 64n + 3 = 0$.